# How to exclude indexing & publishing a symbile file on TFS2015

Tags: .net, tfs, debug-symbols

My project needs to index and publish the .pdb files. But one of the .pdb file from the Autofac NuGet package is not compatible with our TFS builder. So I think I can exclude it.

But I am struggling with the **search pattern** syntax. The "Search pattern" textbox on TFS 2015 is a single line textbox, and I could not find the right way to define multiple search pattern.

I have tried:

1. **\bin\**\*.pdb - the system reports **13** files, but got error when trying to index **Autofac.pdb**.
2. **\bin\**\*.pdb !**\Autofac.pdb - the system reports 0 symbol found.
3. **\bin\**\*.pdb;!**\Autofac.pdb - the system seems to ignore the part behind ';'.
4. **\bin\**\*.pdb;-:**\Autofac.pdb - the system reports **9** files, no error has been reported.

My questions are:

1. What is the correct syntax to include multiple search patterns?
2. How to get a list of symbol files that have been indexed and published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the search pattern (rooted at the path supplied in the previous input) used to discover pdbs that contain symbols which will follow **[file matching patterns reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops#doubleexcl_examples)**.

> About exclude  patterns :
>
> - Leading **`!`** changes the meaning of an include pattern to exclude.    You can include a pattern, exclude a subset of it, and
>     then    re-include a subset of that: this is known as an "interleaved"
>     pattern.
> - Multiple **`!`** flips the meaning.
> - You must define an include pattern before an exclude one.

For [task version2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops), we usually directly wrap lines to exclude `Autofac.pdb` , such as

[image]

However, in your case  seems you are still using version1 of the task which use the pattern that was used by the 1.x Agent's Powershell SDK.

Then you should **use the old format:** `**/bin/**/*.pdb;-:**\Autofac.pdb` the last one you used.

`"-:"` indicates an exclude pattern. Separate multiple patterns using `;`

More details please refer this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/FullHelp/Find-VstsFiles.md).

---

How to get a list of symbol files that have been indexed and published.

You could directly remote to the build server which hold those files and manually check it.